# PowerShell script to show LockState of personal site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

I would love to have a script to show a LockState of ALL personal site on a sharepoint.com
I have tried this:

`$allSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit all -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" foreach ($site in $allSites) { $site where -LockState NoAccess }`

but it doesn't work.
I am very bad with PowerShell, my organisation forced me to do some stuff, while knowing that I am pretty bad (they don't care :(). I am trying to learn fast, but so far ForEach and where are beyond my ability and when I read documentation. So far I know how to connect to data and perform some basic operation like listing a personal sites or changing LockState.

I would be very grateful for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the folowing code:

```
   $Sites =  Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Template "SPSPERS#10"  
    Foreach($Site in $Sites){      
        Write-Host $Site.Url  
        Write-Host $Site.LockState
    }
```